# Laravel : How to count in query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following query :

```
App\User::join('gift_sents', function($builder){
      $builder->on('gift_sents.receiver_id', '=', 'users.id');
      })
      ->select('users.*', 'COUNT(gift_sents.receiver_id as total_posts')
      ->groupBy('gift_sents.id')
      ->orderBy('total_posts', 'ASC')
      ->limit(3)->get();
```

The count isn't working, Its supposed to be working !

The following error comes up :

`Column not found: 1054 Unknown 
column 'COUNT(gift_sents.receiver_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select`users`.*,`COUNT(gift_sents`.`receiver_id`as`total_posts`from`users`inner join`gift_sents`on`gift_sents`.`receiver_id`=`users`.`id`group by`gift_sents`.`id`order by`total_posts`asc limit 3)`

Comment: You have a typo in your select statement, make sure to close your COUNT open parenthesis. `->select('users.*', 'COUNT(gift_sents.receiver_id as total_posts)')`

Comment: Still not working !

Comment: Error: `Unknown column 'count(gift_sents.receiver_id)'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
->select('users.*', 'COUNT(gift_sents.receiver_id as total_posts')
```

you should use:

```
->selectRaw('users.*, COUNT(gift_sents.receiver_id) as total_posts')
```

Answer (score 6):

i think it should be:

```
  ->select('users.*', DB::raw('COUNT(gift_sents.receiver_id) as total_posts'))
```

see doc [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries) - 'Raw Expressions' section