# Unknown column total when using where

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have made this query:

```
        $query = UserHistoryAccess::with('user')
        ->select('user_history_accesses.*', DB::raw('count(user_history_accesses.id) as total'))
        ->join('users', 'user_history_accesses.user_id', 'users.id')
        ->groupBy('user_history_accesses.user_id')
        ->where('total', 'like', '%' . $term . '%')
    ;
```

Even I have followed this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38414545/3866856) but I got this error :

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'total' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `user_history_accesses` inner join `users` on `user_history_accesses`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` where `total` like %388%) in file C:\xampp\htdocs\HabilitisBack\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 671

Comment: which table has the `total` column here?

Comment: @sta , total is an alias of  `count(user_history_accesses.id)` not column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can not use result colum in the where, you should recalculate it in the where to get the desired result, but try using 'having':

```
 ->having('total', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
```